# How can I programatically remove user identity info from doc and docx files?

Tags: java, tags, ms-word, metadata

Is this possible to programatically remove user identity info from doc and docx files (document properties) Using Java tools like POI or any other commandline tool?

Comment: poi seems to have functionality for that: https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hpsf/SummaryInformation.html

Comment: Yes, do it with POI or docx4j (which uses POI for binary doc support).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried POI? I think one should be able to read and edit those attributes- though have not tried though.

You may want to look at [DocumentSummaryInformation](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hpsf/DocumentSummaryInformation.html) class.

You can add/change custom properties - standard or non-standard one.  Check 'Reading Non-Standard Properties section' [here](http://poi.apache.org/hpsf/how-to.html#sec4).

Answer (score 1):

POI does not support image removal it seems. So many unanswered questions are there for image remove. And i personally couldn't find even a single supporting document for image.